# Why do Muay Thai players wear armbands?

Tags: muay-thai

[image]

Is there any technical reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. The best answer is that it's traditional to wear them.

Apocryphally, it is supposed to harken back to a custom where mothers would give their sons, who were going off to war, good-luck charms which they made from cloth torn from their own surong.

In more modern times, they often denote accomplishment and rank within a Muay Thai organization.